# Why I get "cannot find symbol: method toUnmodifiableList()" runtime error?

Tags: java

I want to create an unmodifiable list but I get the following error. Current JDK that I'm using is 11.

```
package com.example.demo;


import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> result = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4)
                .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList());
    }

}
```

Output:

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method toUnmodifiableList()
  location: class java.util.stream.Collectors
```

[image]

Update:

I get this error just for `toUnmodifiableList()` when I run Main.java class inside my SpringBoot project as a separate java file, but changing `toUnmodifiableList()` to `toList()` method works fine.

```
List<Integer> result = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()); // this works
```

Then, I created a simple Java project and there both methods work fine.

[image]

Comment: Does [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-or-cannot-resolve-symbol-error-mean) help you?

Comment: How are you running an compiling the program?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: This is a build issue. Have you set Java version in your build file?

Comment: This suggests you're building with either Java 8, or with Java 10 or higher with `-release 8` or `-release 9`. The warning in IntelliJ is because you have the language level of your project set to 9 or lower. Given you seem to be using Maven (given the `target` directory in one of your screenshots), you likely haven't explicitly configured the source/target Java version, or it is explicitly configured on a lower Java version. It would be helpful if you provide a [mre] including a pom.xml.

Answer (score 1):

Check those 2 places on Intelij and make sure of proper java version

[image]

[image]

Using JDK 15 I can't reproduce the error. So it must have to do with your java configurations

[image]

Check on the second image there where it says Project language level (It is next to Project SDK level). That was what Intelij configured. Try to modify it again and see the error.

Comment: These configurations are correct and set to JDK 11.

Answer (score 0):

The command `mvn clean install` caused Intellij to show me the problem.

[image]

The problem was the `Language level` in `Project Structures` -> `Modules` which I had to set to 10 or above.

[image]